# How do I convert the double to vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, random, type-conversion, double

I have a function which only take vector as input; however, I need to use rand(x) as input variable but rand function only returns a double type. Is there any way to convert double to vector??
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are a few ways:

```
X = rand(1, 10);

VE1 = X(:);

VE2 = reshape(X, 1, []);

VE3 = reshape(X, numel(X), 1);
```

reference: [www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/44156](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/44156-conversion-of-2d-array-in-to-vector?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)